# ParallelStream different results invoking API Rest

Tags: java, rest, lambda, parallel-processing, stream

I have to send 100K request to an API, but in sequential order it takes so long.

So, I'm using ParallelStream. However, a small group of responses is different compared to sequential ones.

I have to read a CSV file with the 100K requests, so I'm reading in this way:

```
lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then, I make the call:

```
IRestClient restClient = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .baseUri(new URI("http://uri"), String.class)))
                    .build(IRestClient.class);
    
List<DTO> results  = lines.parallelStream()
                              .map(line -> makeHttpCall(line, restClient ))      
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
public ObjectDTO makeHttpCall(String line, IRestClient restClient )  {
        String[] srt = line.split(";", -1);
        ObjectDTO record = new ObjectDTO();
        int i=0;
        record.setXXX(srt[i++]);
        record.setXXX(srt[i++]);
        record.setXXX(srt[i++]);
        record.setXXX(srt[i++]);

        try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()){
            ObjectDTO responseDto = restClient.getRest(jsonb.toJson(record));
            return responseDto;
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

The method `makeHttpCall` reads each line (string) and converts from CSV to DTO and then, to JSON. With that JSON, I make the http call and the response is a JSON that I convert to DTO and return it.

The process takes 20 minutes (compared with hours in sequential order) but some results are wrong.

I suppose some results are mixed because of parallel stream but I don't know how to resolve it.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I can think of 3 possible reasons: - your data is not independent (meaning line x must be sent before line x+1), - `makeHttpCall()` is not thread safe, - the Rest API is not thread safe.

Comment: I believe it would be nice to have a code of the "makeHttpCall", something wrong could be there.

Comment: Updated with the methods source code, thanks

Comment: parallelStream is not suitable for sequential execution/iteration. It doesn't call makeHttpCall method sequentially, so you are getting different responses compared to sequential ones.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need sequential requests, so the responses could be messy, because the order is not important. But I need that the responses to be correct (in fact, only a small groups of responses are different).

Comment: Your client code looks kind of okay in terms of thread-safety. Is there any chance that this issue resides on the REST server side?

Comment: Hi, probably yes. I suppose the problem could be in the server side. Thx.